# use gcc to directly compile to machine code without linking

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86

i want to get gcc to compile c-code for me into x86-32 linux binary code, but without any librarys or so around it.
I just want to specify an address at the start, and it should assume it has been loaded there. I will then manually build an elf file from the output by hand and set up everything.

I know how to do something like this using NASM, but i have something more complicated in mind where i don't want to use only assembler. I dont need any librarys, i will use pure syscalls with inline asm. I also do not care much if it looses some portability.

I tried around a bit, but could not find a way to do that.
Can someone not only provide me with the correct settings for that, but also some background on the compile and linker parameters?
I tried searching through the gcc manual, but found it very confusing.

Comment: `gcc -c` compiles + assembles but doesn't link.  But it sounds like what you really need is a linker script to produce a flat binary instead of an ELF executable.  Or `objcopy` to copy a section of a linked executable to a flat binary.

Comment: i tried objcopy, but it just gave me some bogus. I could not even find the opcodes from the output file in the file objcopy gave me. Also, i would need the addresses to match up, or only have position independent code. So yeah, it sounds like i would indeed need some way to tell the linker what i want

Comment: Linker scripts exist to tell the linker what you want. See   https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones#Linking_the_Kernel, or many Stack Overflow answers with linker scripts.  If you don't want to go completely PIC, then yeah you'll want to link your code into a static executable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to get gcc to compile c-code for me into x86-32 linux binary code, but without any librarys or so around it.

That means you write *freestanding* C code. (When the standard library is available, you have a *hosted* environment; when not, a *freestanding* one. )

To compile e.g. foo.c to an executable, foo, make sure it has a `_start()` function, and use

```
gcc -march=i686 -mtune=generic -m32 -ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostartfiles foo.c -o foo
```

The GNU toolchain uses the address of the `_start` symbol to encode the start address of the executable in the ELF file.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39932430/1475978) is an actual real-world example for x86-64.  For x86-32 (or any other architecture), you'll need to adjust the `SYSCALL_` macros.

---

In a comment, OP explains they want a binary blob, instead of an ELF executable.

In this case, it is best to tell the compiler to generate a [position independent executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code). For example, 'blob.c':

```
void do_something(int arg)
{
    /* Do something with arg, perhaps a syscall,
       or inline assembly? */
}

void loop_something(int from, int to)
{
    int  arg;

    if (from <= to)
        for (arg = from; arg <= to; arg++)
            do_something(arg);
    else
        for (arg = from; arg <= to; arg--)
            do_something(arg);
}

void _start(void)
{
    loop_something(2, 5);
    do_something(6);
    loop_something(5, 2);
    do_something(1);
}
```

I do recommend declaring all functions except `_start` as `static`, to avoid any global offset table (GOT) or procedure linkage table (PLT) references (like `<__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>` calls).

Compile this to an position independent executable using e.g.

```
gcc -march=i686 -mtune=generic -m32 -O2 -fPIE -ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostartfiles blob.c -o blob
```

strip it,

```
strip --strip-all blob
```

and dump the contents of the binary:

```
objdump -fd blob
```

In this output, there are two important lines:

```
start address 0x08048120
```

which tells the address of the `_start` symbol, and

```
080480e0 <.text>:
```

which tells the offset of the code, in hexadecimal.  Subtract the former from the latter (0x08048120 - 0x080480e0 = 0x40 = 64) to get the offset of the start symbol.

Finally, dump the code into a raw binary file 'blob.raw' using

```
objcopy -O binary -j .text blob blob.raw
```

Comment: that points into the right direction, but is not quite what i want. I do not want it to output an executable. I want it to output a binary blob, which will only work if it gets somehow mapped at the specified address and manually jumped into.
I do not want an elf.

Edit: To clarify: i want something i can manually put together using a hex editor

Comment: Also, I won't need any syscall macros, as I will use inline asm and manually call int 80

Comment: @Boldar: That's exactly what the syscall macros are, inline asm.

Comment: @Boldar: I added an example of how to generate a flat raw binary file containing the compiled position independent executable code from a C source file.

Comment: Thank you, thats more or less what i want. One last Bonus: can i force a specific order of the functions? E.g. when i have code like in your example, can i tell gcc that i want the _start function to be the first in output? Or, how determines gcc the order of functions in the output?

Comment: @Boldar: I don't know, but I think they are in the order they are defined. (That is, in the order the functions are implemented in, not in the order they are declared in.)